# Heroku caching old routes?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, callback

I have a weird issue. I've got a Rails 4 app using Devise / OmniAuth Facebook running.

Login and callback work just fine locally. However, when I deploy to Heroku and then attempt to login with FB, the callback fails and I get the cryptic `We're sorry but something went wrong' error.

`heroku logs` and `heroku addons:open papertrail`, show me very little other than the following:

```
014-11-03T18:38:59.138399+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/MY_OLD_PATH" host=MY_APP.herokuapp.com request_id=f6924bd0-02e0-4172-9fa3-eaa3e6ce1ace fwd="50.112.95.211" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=404 bytes=1829
```

It seems that the Heroku router is still using some old routes which I removed a long time ago. I've searched my entire app and have no instance of this route or related methods/views anywhere.

SO I figure Heroku's caching something. I added `gem 'heroku-repo'` and ran a couple repo rebuild / reset commands, nothing changed. I also cleared my browser cache.

Not sure what I'm missing!

Comment: What is the redirect_uri you are passing to Facebook? It looks like its still the /MY_OLD_PATH and the Heroku router is just returning a 404 for that as it should.

Comment: Unfortunately I never figured out what it was. I ended up having to delete the Heroku app and redeploy as a new app. This ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I never figured out what it was. I ended up having to delete the Heroku remote and redeploying this as a new app. This ended up working.